# Adding a guest user to Microsoft Planner

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-planner

I am trying to add an external guest to a Microsoft Planner task and am getting the usual "You need to request access from your admin".

I have created the user in Ad and 365, they have been added to the task and I am able to see them, however when the user tries to connect to the task they are getting the error above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your Manage groups guest access: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office365/admin/create-groups/manage-guest-access-in-groups?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fmanage-guest-access-in-office-365-groups-9de497a9-2f5c-43d6-ae18-767f2e6fe6e0&view=o365-worldwide#manage-groups-guest-access. Make sure that "Let group members outside the organization access group content" is **On**.

Comment: Any updates from your side? Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, Yeah that was it, but was hesitant to see what access guests would have when selecting this, seems that they are still only able to access the resource I enabled them to access.

Comment: It is equivalent to a master switch for controlling guest users' access to group content. If you don't mind, I will add an answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@allen Wu - your solution seems to have solved my problem

"Check your Manage groups guest access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/manage-guest-access-in-groups?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fmanage-guest-access-in-office-365-groups-9de497a9-2f5c-43d6-ae18-767f2e6fe6e0&view=o365-worldwide#manage-groups-guest-access. Make sure that "Let group members outside the organization access group content" is On. – Allen Wu"

Answer (score 0):

Check your [Manage groups guest access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/manage-guest-access-in-groups?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fmanage-guest-access-in-office-365-groups-9de497a9-2f5c-43d6-ae18-767f2e6fe6e0&view=o365-worldwide#manage-groups-guest-access).

Make sure that "Let group members outside the organization access group content" is **On**.

It is equivalent to a master switch for controlling guest users' access to group content

[image]